# How could I generate a vector field to mimic the graph in the picture below?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

for educational purposes I want to generate a vector field starting from a graph found in my book*.

Would anyone of you be so kind as to suggest a function that approximates the graph in this picture?

Many thanks in advance.

[image: dynamics of the RCK model in Economics, source: Romer textbook]

*Advanced Macroeconomics, David Romer, McGraw-Hill, 4th ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $f(k)$ the boundary where $\dot k=0$. For a given $(k,c)$ pair, the horizontal component is positive if $c<f(k)$, is zero if $c=f(k)$ and is negative if $c>f(k)$. You can use the sign function for example $$\textrm{sgn}(x)=\cases{1,x>0\\0, x=0\\ -1,x<0}$$ to write the horizontal component as $\textrm{sgn}(f(k)-c)$. Similarly, the vertical component will be $\textrm{sgn}(k^*-k)$, So your vector field is $$\vec v=\left(\textrm{sgn}(f(k)-c),\textrm{sgn}(k^*-k)\right)$$
If you want a smooth function (no jumps), just use any odd function instead of the sign function. For example $$\vec v=\left(f(k)-c,k^*-k\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I have another question: how should I implement this solution, especially for the second component of the vector? The first one is straightforward, it could be i.e. x^3 - 2, but how would I write the second one? In particular, I really don't understand how to represent that k*. What arguments should I enter at the following link? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eijhparfmd

Comment: For example $F_1(x,y)=-0.05x^2+5-y$ and $F_2(x,y)=-x$

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you again.